# Using NAS device as SQL server backup target

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have used NAS devices as backup targets for SQL server databases. I have used them as file shares which are mapped to servers holding databases. Thing is that our current NAS supports iSCSI protocol and was wondering if I can use NAS LUNs (mapped as drives) in the SQL server virtual servers and take advantage of the protocol? Anyone who has tried this before or know about some difficulties/deficiencies using this method. Thanks.

Comment: Be mindful to follow iSCSI best practices, even if it's just a NAS device instead of a SAN.  You'll want to have these going to a different NIC in a different subnet/network with preferred direct connect in this scenario but if going through a router ensure it has jumbo frames, the right amount of ram, and so fourth.  In that scenario you could even use it as local storage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drive mapped iSCSI targets work perfectly for SQL Server backup destinations.

Map the iSCSI target into your VM as a drive, assign a drive letter inside the VM, and just do normal backups as you would to any other target.

I use that exact process for my clustered SQL Servers.

Comment: Thank you Max, those are the exact words going around my head about how to do the process, just needed some confirmation based on experience and you did it.